# Matlab: Include a part of the path to file when using dir command

Tags: matlab, path, dir

I'm trying to get a path to all the jpeg files in a directory including 'fig'. This code below gets all the jpeg files in the directory, however does not exclude any 'rft' labeled files.

```
base_directory = '/home/user/data/';
directories = dir([base_directory,'/*.jpg']);
filenames = directories;
```

An example of the directory is

```
goblet_fig_2004_03_07.jpg
goblet_rft_2004_03_07.jpg
goblet_fig_2004_11_02.jpg
goblet_rft_2004_11_02.jpg
```

Any help is appreciated.

After help this is my complete code, Notice '*fig*.jpg', was the answer I was looking for

```
base_directory = '/home/user/data/';                                
directories = dir([base_directory,'*fig*.jpg']);                             
filenames = directories;                                                   
for fileIndex = 1: length(filenames)  
    image = imread([base_directory,'/',filenames(fileIndex).name]);    
end
```

Comment: What's the question?

And you use two slashes in a row, is that correct?

Comment: How do I code the dir command to only get files including 'fig' and '.jpg'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
filenames = dir('*fig*.jpg')
```

I have tried it on Windows, not Linux, but it should work.

Comment: Technically the filenames would now be filenames.name.

Comment: I cannot get this code to work in my R2012b? What am I doing wrong!

Comment: Certainly, of course I am just sifting through .m and .txt since I don't have figs handy, but I could not get this code right. Oh well.

Comment: Of course. You can bypass that easily by just typing that into the console already in a directory of jpg and fig files. But its okay no worries.

Answer (score 1):

A simple answer is this:

```
directories = [dir('*.fig'); dir('*.jpg')]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using regular expressions for instance

```
directories = {'goblet_fig_2004_03_07.jpg'
'goblet_rft_2004_03_07.jpg'
'goblet_fig_2004_11_02.jpg'
'goblet_rft_2004_11_02.jpg'};

directories(~cellfun('isempty',regexp(directories,'fig')))
```

returns

```
ans = 

    'goblet_fig_2004_03_07.jpg'
    'goblet_fig_2004_11_02.jpg'
```

Other functions such as `findstr` probably work too.